# Play Framework 2 paginating data from a web service

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

There have been several Play Framework pagination questions but all have been using JPA or ebean.  I need to paginate data I am getting returned from a web service.  Is there a way to do this with the Play Pagination Module or am I stuck with jQuery? I am also new to play and Java coming from asp.net MVC. The web service is returning a List of whatever model I am querying.

Answer (score 1):

You should not paginate results from web service in the Play's controller as it would be not optimal, consider 3 scenarios (in that order)

Let's say that you want to display 10 items at once, but your generator returns 100.000 for sample query (which means 10.000 of pages)

1. Pagination should be done by data generator (web service in this case), so you should sent a query containg data: `what are you looking for`, `how big page you want to get` and `which page you need` ie: `?q=pagination&size=10&page=123`. This will respond with List of 10 items on page 123. If you have possibility to change the web service to add pagination it's best choice.
2. If web service doesn't offer pagination get all results at once and use jQuery to paginate it. So if you'll get set of 100.000 items put all of them to the client and make sure that every page change won't cause querying the web service. Poor option, but still better than next one.
3. You can iterate returned results to split it easily to the pages, count total amount, etc, etc. If you'll use controller for paginating it, at every page change it will be fetching 100.000 items and then splitting to display just 10 of them. Drama :)

So if you can't use first option and don't want to use jQuery make some caching of the results on your server (ie, by storing results in the database as a separate rows) - in such case you will be able to use Ebean for local searching and paging.